# Error:Exception:Use of undefined constant ICONV_IMPL - assumed 'ICONV_IMPL'

Tags: magento2, error

Now the site doesn't show and we get the following Error on the home page

> Exception: Notice: Use of undefined constant ICONV_IMPL - assumed
> 'ICONV_IMPL' in
> /home/tassosco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/StringUtils.php
> on line 162 in
> /home/tassosco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/tassosco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/StringUtils.php(162):
> Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Use of undefine...',
> '/home/tassosco/...', 162, Array) #1
> /home/tassosco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Header.php(120):
> Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils->cleanString('Mozilla/5.0
> (X1...') #2
> /home/tassosco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Header.php(57):
> Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header->_getHttpCleanValue('HTTP_USER_AGENT',
> true) #3
> /home/tassosco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderProvider/XssProtection.php(43):
> Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header->getHttpUserAgent() #4
> /home/tassosco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(42):
> Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XssProtection->getValue()
>
> ## 5 /home/tassosco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(123):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>
> ## 6 /home/tassosco/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse',
> Array, Array) #7
> /home/tassosco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(185):
> Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #8
> /home/tassosco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(156):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
> Object(Exception)) #9
> /home/tassosco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
> Object(Exception)) #10 /home/tassosco/public_html/index.php(39):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
>
> ## 11 {main}

please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You have to go into your php.ini file and uncomment this

```
[iconv]
;iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1
```

So that it looks like this

```
[iconv]
iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1
```

Also change this

```
;intl.error_level = E_WARNING
```

Into this

```
intl.error_level = 0
```

And make sure you have installed php extensions: php-iconv and php-intl, then restart apache.